# How do i combine these print statements?

Tags: python

```
word = input("Translate a word: ")
for char in word:
    if char in "BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZbcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz":
        print(char + "o" + char)
    else:
        print(char)
```

I have this code for a translator to a language where you add an "o" after each consonant followed by that same consonant again. When i run it and type in for example "stair" it would print out:

```
sos
tot
a
i
ror
```

If someone has an idea on how to print this out on the same line without spacing i would be very grateful!

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-newline-or-space

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print without newline or space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-newline-or-space)

Comment: `print('something',end='')`

Comment: Looks like a children's play language I once read about in an Astrid Lindren book :)

Comment: While the question you asked is already answered as duplicate, I think you really need to define a translate function. Then, assuming it's Lindren, your print statement would be: print(translate_to_rovarspraket(word))

Answer (score 3):

Don't print each time but append the result to a string and print the final string:

```
word = input("Translate a word: ")
result = ''
for char in word:
    if char not in "aeiouyAEIOUY":
        result+=char + "o" + char
    else:
        result+=char
print(result)
```

Comment: I like this solution than others but as pointed out by @KennyOstrom there is nothing wrong with your approach it is just adhering to the best practices and keep the related logic encapsulating in a single function. It makes no sense to submit a new answer just with the same logic and an extra function defined.

Comment: I suggested an improvement to this answer. I could propose an edit, but instead I deleted my comment and commented directly to OP.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use list comprehension to create a list with your values:

```
[char+'o'+char if char in "BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZbcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz" else char for char in word]
```

and then if you need to smash them together into a string you just use a join()

```
''.join([char+'o'+char if char in "BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZbcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz" else char for char in word])
```

Comment: while it works, your answer is way more complicated than it has to be, the OP could just print without a newline at the end.

Comment: Why promoting list comprehension when the answer does not necessarily need it? Seriously for printing in new line you have to create a new list??

Answer (score 0):

Add records to a list and use `print` function with `*` to print records in the same line.

```
word = input("Translate a word: ")
data = []  #create a empty list
for char in word:
    if char in "BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZbcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz":
        data.append(char + "o" + char)  #add elements to list
    else:
        data.append(char)  #add elements to list

print(*data, sep='')  #print list elements in single line without spaces
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the print statement as you are currently doing, just try below option of print statement which defines the ending of the print statement.

```
word = input("Translate a word: ")
for char in word:
    if char in "BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZbcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz":
        print(char + "o" + char,end="")
    else:
       print(char,end="")
```

The output of the above code on input "stair" will be "sostotairor". Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

You can double the consonants in a list first and join the characters with `o`:

```
word = input("Translate a word: ")
for char in word.lower():
    print('o'.join([char] * ((char not in 'aeiou') + 1)))
```

Sample input/output:

```
Translate a word: stair
sos
tot
a
i
ror
```